# Having trouble with jquery callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I have an accordion in an html, the headers onclick call a function initTable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
    $('.accordion ul li h1').click(function() 
    {                
      document.getElementById('processing').innerHTML = "Processing...";
      document.body.style.cursor = 'Wait';
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.ac:visible').slideToggle().parent().removeClass('active');

      if ($(this).next().is(':hidden'))
      {
        $(this).next().slideToggle().parent().addClass('active'); 
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=processing></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="accordion">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h1 onclick=initTable("Anticoag")>Anticoag</h1>
          <div class="ac">
            <div id="AnticoagTable" width="100%">Loading...</div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

The initTable hits the server to get data and creates a DataTable, which takes a few seconds.

What I'm trying to do is set my div id='processing' to "Processing..." BEFORE the initTable call happens.

Right now what's happening is that it's waiting for the table data to come back, THEN displaying "Processing..."

I tried changing my h1 to onclick=test1(category), with this code.  But for some reason my initTable function isn't even getting called with this.  Don't know if it's syntax or I'm using it completely wrong.

```
function test1(category)
{
  test2(category, function()
  {
    initTable(category);
  });
}

function test2(category)
{
  alert("test2");
  document.getElementById('processing').innerHTML = "Processing...";
  document.body.style.cursor = 'Wait';
}
```

adding initTable function by request
    function initTable(category) {
        if (gsCategory === "") gsCategory = category;
        else if (gsCategory == category) gbToggle = !gbToggle;
        else gbToggle = false;

```
    gsCategory = category;

    if (gbToggle === false) {
        gsCategory = category;

        var select = document.forms[0].selFacility;
        var facility = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

        var patJson = getJson(facility, category);
        document.getElementById('processing').innerHTML = "Done...";
        document.body.style.cursor = 'Default';
        var anOpen = [];
        var sImageUrl = "../images/";
        makeTable(category);

        var oTable = $('#' + category).dataTable({
            "bProcessing": false,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aaData": patJson,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "aoColumns": [{
                "mDataProp": null,
                    "sClass": "control center",
                    "sDefaultContent": '<img src="' + sImageUrl + 'details_open.png' + '">',
                    "sWidth": "5%"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "S_PAT_NAME",
                    "sWidth": "30%"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "S_AGE",
                    "sWidth": "15%"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "S_FIN",
                    "sWidth": "30%"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "S_ROOM_BED",
                    "sWidth": "20%"
            }]
        });

        $('#' + category + ' td.control').live('click', function () {
            var nTr = this.parentNode;
            var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

            if (i === -1) {
                $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_close.png");
                var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
                $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
                anOpen.push(nTr);
            } else {
                $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_open.png");
                $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp(function () {
                    oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                    anOpen.splice(i, 1);
                });
            }
        });
    } //gbToggle = false
}
```

Comment: What does your `initTable` function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `initTable(category)` is never called.

`test2`should be :

```
 function test2(category,cb){
  alert("test2");
  document.getElementById('processing').innerHTML = "Processing...";
  document.body.style.cursor = 'Wait';
  //Calling the call-back
  cb(category);
 }
```

That's for your actual code.
But you could simply do in your `test1`

```
function test1(category)
{
  test2(category);

  //asynchronous call to initTable().
  setTimeout(function(){
      initTable(category);
  },0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not changing the div until after initTable comes back.  Could it have something to do with the code in document).ready?   I tried both versions above.

Comment: what about putting your `initTable`call in a `setTimeout`? See my update.

Comment: YES!  that worked.  the question now is - why does that work?  And can I mark two answers correct :)  You guys both helped a ton.

Comment: It works because when you call functions like `alert` or do sever calls it stops the javascript execution. And restart it when possible. The fix is to put these in timeouts so it becomes asynchronous.

Comment: I don't think you can accept two answers as correct.
You can upvote the one which helped you, and accept the one which fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already assigned a function to click with jQuery, you don't need and shouldn't use `onclick` attribute

Just put the initTable call inside the click handler function. To recognize what was clicked you can use a `data-something` attribute

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  $('.accordion ul li h1').click(function()  {  
  var category = $(this).attr('data-category');

  $('#processing')..text("Processing...");
  ...
  initTable( category );



<h1 data-category="Anticoag">Anticoag</h1>
```

You also need to:

- know that in javascript it is incorrect to put `{` in a new line
- get some understanding on what happens when you pass an inline function to other function, because you did

  test2(category, function()
    {
      initTable(category);
    });

And you didn't even declare a second argument in the `test2` function definition.

Comment: Sorry, old habits on the {    Changed my function and h1 tag as you suggested and it's setting div to "Processing", but still only after the initTable has come back

Comment: nothing to be sorry about, in some cases it just won't work correctly :)
Looking at your code update I see that you are downloading the data synchronously, which I just did not expect. If you're using jquery anywat, just use it to get data. In your current case, move the initTable call after the part that shows `processing...`. Updating my answer

Comment: I have to make a call to some proprietary functionality in getJson. getJson calls a database query script (the proprietary part) which returns my json string.  So unfortunately I can't use jquery to grab it directly.  I wish I could, it would have made the dataTable a lot easier to use.

Comment: BTW I did try moving the initTable call after $('#processing - still no luck.

Comment: Ok, if we're to move it any forward, you'll have to publish it somewhere and post a link. Then I'll be able to help directly

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and suggestions.  Although YoannM got me the last piece of the puzzle, your suggestions got me to the point that I could use it.